# Modify Contact Associated View to include prospects

Tags: view, entity, criteria, crm, contacts

We have Contact Associated View that displays all customers. These are people who have bought one or more item from the high street shop or online. But we also have a set of customers who goes to the shop and signup for news letters and offers. In our setup these are called PROSPECTs.

My current view (Contact Associated View) only displays customers but not prospect and I was wondering what is the best way to include them in this view? I don't want to create another cusom view as I don't know what the criterias are.

Also, if there is any way to find out what criteria is used to create Contact Associated View and if it is practicle to make changes in it.

Any guidance or tutorial link would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

EDIT: I manage to create a custom view under CONTACT which SUPPOSE to list all customers who purchased or didn't purchase item from that shop. 
Simple check like Customer equal y;n

but when I view contacts from this view, it only list customers with purchase. Is there any master condition that is overwriting this condition or am I missing some thing? (*forgive me if I sound stupid but I am from SharePoint world where master CSS rules takes over local CSS rules*)

Comment: Whats the relationship model here?

Comment: Each contact in the DB is marked with the flag Customer (y/n) and Prospect (y/n). When contact signup with out new letter they get marked as Prospect (Y) and Customer (N). When they make purchase from any shop they get marked as Prospect (N) and Customer (Y). These customers then gets listed under each shop where they made purchase. 

In some cases customer goes and signup for new letter in a perticular shop but DON'T make any purchase. Because we are only listing customer under each shop, these contacts who signed up in the shop doesn't show up in that list. I hope this help!! pheww

Comment: So, how many relationships are there between customer and shop?

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you looking for but customerID, shopemaillist(Y/N), SourceShop (tells which shop customer made first purchase) and EmailSubscriber (Y/N)... not sure if this is what you asked for when you say, relationship between shop and customer. Bottom line, each contact/customer is listed by SourceShop.